# Trouble with synchronisation errors / conflicts in Outlook

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin

We have an addin that saves additional data back into the email which is causing conflicts when office 365 processes the email and 'returns' the sent copy back to the mailbox.

We have identified that saving the information back to the email after exchange has received a copy to process the message is what causes the issue but we don't know how to solve this. Does anyone have any advice how to go about modifying the UserProperties values without causing conflicts?

Comment: Where and when do you set/change the user property value?

Answer (score 0):

Do not save the message twice - set the data before it is saved for the very first time. Or keep your custom data elsewhere - associated (hidden) content table is the standard location.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to avoid adding custom data to items in Outlook. But the best what you can do is to avoid weak places that could cause such issues.